# Redux Toolkit & TypeScript: Error: Type WritableDraft<X> is missing the following properties from type WritableDraft<X>

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am having trouble assigning a value to a key with Redux Toolkit and TypeScript

```
export interface AnimalToStateMap {
    [ANIMAL.cat]: (LargeCatState, SmallCatState)[],
    [ANIMAL.dog (LargeDogState, SmallDogState)[],
    [ANIMAL.fish]: (WhaleState, FishState)[]
}

type AnimalValues<T> = T[keyof T];
export type AllAnimalTpyes = AnimalValues<AnimalToStateMap>;

export interface FooState {
    animals: AllAnimalTpyes,
    queue: { [key: string]: { index: number, animal: AllActivityTypes } },
}

const initialState: FooState {
    animals: [...],
    queue: { },
}

export const animals = createSlice({
    name: 'animals',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        removeAnimal: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ index: number, id: string, }>) => {
            const {index, id} = action.payload
            const animal = state.animals.at(index)
            if (animal) state.queue[id] = {index, animal}
            state.animals.splice(index, 1)
        },
})
```

This highlights

```
state.queue[id] = {index, animal}
```

With the compiler error

> TS2740: Type  `WritableDraft<FooState>`  is missing the following properties from type  `WritableDraft <FooState>[]` :  length, pop, push, concat , and  29  more.

If I change this `state.queue[id] = {index, animal}` to  `state.queue[id] = {index, animal: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(animal))}` it works. It also works with a `//@ts-ignore` so it is a TypeScript problem...

Why?